The sum of four number is divisible by three of them. Find the remainder when the sum is divided by the fourth number.
Four different three-digit numbers have the same hundreds digit. Their sum is divisible by three of them. Find the remainder when the sum is divided by the fourth number.

Assume that four numbers are: a, b, c, d. So $|x-y| < 100$ with x, y belonging to the set {a, b, c, d}. S = a+b+c+d, S is divisible to a, b and c


I can find those four numbers: 108, 135, 180 and 117. However, I don't know how to solve this problem by math

I would appreciate any help, especially a hint or approach that I can use to find the rest of the solution on my own!

The problem comes from IIMC 2018 Keystage 2 (EMIC), according to https://chiuchang.org/imc/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/07/BIMC-2018_Keystage-2_Team-1.x17381.pdf, problem 6 from the Team category


What is the source of the problem, and what is your math education?

The problem seems to come from IIMC 2018 Keystage 2 (EMIC), according to https://chiuchang.org/imc/en/%e6%ad%b7%e5%b1%86%e8%a9%a6%e9%a1%8c/2018-2/, specifically, problem 6 from the Team category.
I believe the contest was for upper primary school students.

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS thread Find all possible values. The problem there is somewhat different, but it has in Post #2 just a list of the same $4$ values as you found (although note it's not correct for the stated problem there!).

Please show what you've tried. Esp since you've found some numerical solutions, what can we say about the values? Hint: $1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 > 1 $

@user2661923 I'm studying math with my son

What is the source of the problem?

@user2661923 I have attached the link in my question. It comes from BIMC contest. https://chiuchang.org/imc/en/%e6%ad%b7%e5%b1%86%e8%a9%a6%e9%a1%8c/2018-2/

Let the 4 numbers be $a, b, c, d$ with $a+b+c+d = S$.
Let $ \frac{S}{a} = p, \frac{S}{b} = q, \frac{S}{c} = r$ be integers with $ p >  q > r$.
Let $ \frac{S}{d} = t$, which need not be an integer.
We have $ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{t} = 1$, which might be a familiar setup.
Hint: The condition that they have the same hundreds digit means that they occur in a small range, namely $|a-b| < 100$. However, since we're dealing with multiples/fractions of $S$, it might be more helpful to let $ \frac{1}{2} < \frac{a}{d} < 2$ (and similar inequalities), which means $ \frac{1}{2} < \frac{ t}{p} < 2 $ (and similar inequalities).
Now, consider cases conditioning on the value of $p$.
Show that $p = 4$ has no solutions.
Show that $p = 5$ yields a single solution which you have found.
Show that $ p \geq 6$ has no solutions.

Hint Here's an outline of one approach.
Denote the common hundreds digit by $h$ and the number of times each factor goes into the sum $S$ by $p, q, r$ (w.l.o.g. assume $2 \leq p < q < r$), so that the factors are, in increasing size, $\frac{S}{r}, \frac{S}{q}, \frac{S}{p}$.
We can immediately deduce some useful equalities from the problem statement:

Since each factor is between $100 h$ and $100 (h + 1)$, their sum is $400 h \leq S < 400(h + 1)$. Now use $100 h \leq r$ and rearrange to get an upper bound on $r$ in terms of $h$.


 $$\boxed{r < 4 + \frac{4}{h}} .$$


The smallest factor, $\frac{S}{r}$, and the largest factor, $\frac{S}{p}$ both have hundreds digit $h$, i.e., are between $100 h$ and $100 (h + 1)$, so $100 h r \leq S < 100 (h + 1) p$, hence $(r - p) h < p$. The second inequality specializes in some helpful ways.


 Since $r \geq p + 2$, we have $\boxed{2 h < p}$, and since $h \geq 1$, $(r - p) \leq (r - p) h < p$, hence $\boxed{r < 2 p}$.

Combine these bounds to determine $h$ and produce bounds for $p, S$.

Together these bounds gives $h = 1$, $p \geq 3$ (also $p \leq 5$, but we won't need that fact), and $500 < S < 600$. From here, consider separately the cases $p = 3$ (which yields the solution mentioned in the question statement) and $p > 3$ (in which case the fourth number is both at least $S - \frac{S}{4} - \frac{S}{5} - \frac{S}{6} = \frac{23 S}{60}$ and smaller than $200$). It may also be helpful to recall that since $p, q, r$ divide $S$ evenly, $S$ is a multiple of $\operatorname{lcm}(p, q, r)$.

